# How do I get my application to show up in the "Open in..." menu on iOS for ANY document type?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have requirement to have my application name in "Open in " menu for any document type in iOS platform in iPAD. It means for any extension my application should be presented in "Open in" menu. One way is that I add all keys in DocumentType UTI but I need some option like whether I can mention "*" to allow all document types.

It is available with `CFBundleTypeExtension` but it is for OS X platform and not for iOS platform. Also for custom extension I need same thing so I don't have to update `.plist` file again and again for new document types.

Let me know whether such thing is possible or not. For more detail or any query ask me and I will try to give more clarification if required.

Comment: to allow all document types to be opened in your App ? Seems messy in User Experience & confusing.

Comment: @rRaptor --> Basically I have requirement to upload all kind of docs received in email application(default mail application) on our server (similar to Dropbox). So I need to upload any document regardless its type. I hope now it is clear

Comment: Only few types of attachments are allowed to be accessible in Mail App, so it's not every attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/01/open-in-all-files/)

In short: Add the UTI `public.item` to the list of handled document types for your app.